# Kotlin BitmapFactory IllegalStateException

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, kotlin

The app I am working on at the moment loads a fragment and renders it to the activity_main.xml , that works fine. Problem is I implemented a RecyclerView and a CardView, so as to list my skills dynamically. Getting an error that goes like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ic_launcher_foreground) must not be null
```

This code is in the Kotlin fragment that loads the respective fragment (**SkillFragment**)

```
package smartline.jjba.storyofmylife

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import smartline.jjba.storyofmylife.R.id.rv
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager


class SkillFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_skills, container, false)

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): SkillFragment = SkillFragment()
}

fun addItemsToCard(items: ArrayList<MyData>) {

    items.run {
        add(MyData("text 1", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)))
        add(MyData("text 2", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_bar_chart_24px)))
        add(MyData("text 3", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_bar_chart_24px)))
        add(MyData("text 4", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_bar_chart_24px)))
        add(MyData("text 5", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_bar_chart_24px)))
        add(MyData("text 6", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_bar_chart_24px)))
    }

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val _recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv)
    _recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)

    var itemList = ArrayList<MyData>()

    addItemsToCard(itemList)

    //creating our adapter
    val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(itemList)

    //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
    _recyclerView.adapter = adapter


}


}
```

I have tried several different drawable resources, but to no avail. Also would be nice to know if there is another method I can call which would render the drawable into Bitmap

This is my data class

```
package smartline.jjba.storyofmylife
import android.graphics.Bitmap

data class MyData(var text:String, var image: Bitmap)
```

This is my Adapter code

```
class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bindItems(data : MyData){
        val _textView:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview)
        val _imageView:ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview)
        _textView.text = data.text
        _imageView.setImageBitmap(data.image)

        //set the onclick listener for the singlt list item
        itemView.setOnClickListener({
            Log.e("ItemClicked", data.text)
        })
    }

}
```

**What I am looking for**

Advice on how to deal with the issue, or information whether it's a known bug in Android or Kotlin. I can probably reinstall the Android Studio on the device and it will be ok again but would not want this happening, also if I can prevent it.

Here is the exception log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: smartline.jjba.storyofmylife, PID: 21687
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeReso…e.ic_launcher_foreground) must not be null
    at smartline.jjba.storyofmylife.SkillFragment.addItemsToCard(SkillFragment.kt:28)
    at smartline.jjba.storyofmylife.SkillFragment.onViewCreated(SkillFragment.kt:44)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Thanks in Advance for this great community!!!

**UPDATE**

thanks to @Kiskae no exceptions anymore yay! 
put a question mark in Bitmap, for Kotlin null check

```
data class MyData(var text:String, var image: Bitmap?)
```

but no images are loaded and the first item also isnt loaded??

[image of items being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gawkM.png)

[image of code adding to array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5m61.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug in Android nor Kotlin, the documentation of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` states:

> The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded, or, if opts is non-null, if opts requested only the size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)

Since you've defined `MyData` to hold a **non-null** `Bitmap` kotlin inserts a check to make sure the returned bitmap is not null, this is where the exception occurs.